# How do I get enabled repos?

Tags: apt, software-sources

Is the only way to open `sources.list` and/or `sources.list.d`?
I'd like to have something like:

```
apt list enabled_repos
```

Comment: What about `cat /etc/apt/sources*`? A GUI version is in your Software & Updates control panel.

Comment: @user535733 I think you want `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`

Comment: @wjandrea, I considered that - the output of both is close enough on mine. It's hard to tell what MysticDog wants yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on what output format you want.

`apt-cache policy` shows the current sources with the priority applied to each:

```
~ apt-cache policy
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-webupd8team-java,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Oracle Java (JDK) 8 / 9 Installer PPA,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-webupd8team-java,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Oracle Java (JDK) 8 / 9 Installer PPA,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-wine,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Wine Team PPA,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-ubuntu-wine,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Wine Team PPA,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-jonathonf-vim,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Vim,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jonathonf/vim/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release v=16.04,o=LP-PPA-jonathonf-vim,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=Vim,c=main,b=amd64
....
```

The information here can be used in other apt configuration, like apt [`preferences`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/apt_preferences.5) or the configuration for `unattended-upgrades`.

You can also use [the Python API](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/aptsources.sourceslist.html):

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import aptsources.sourceslist
sources = sourcesList.SourcesList()
for source in sources:
    if not (source.disabled or source.invalid):
        print(source.line.strip())
```

Which gives output like:

```
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial universe
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates universe
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse
deb http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
```